# SSL Certs for single IP- two ports, same URL website

Tags: iis, dns, websphere, jdedwards

We've a project that is to go live very soon and we ran into this issue when dealing with developers. This is two JDEdwards (ERP) website which are hosted on a single IBM WebSphere webserver, currently using a FQDN, and different ports assignment for DEV and TEST users. Websites as such are -

DEV

https://jdeweb01dev.corporate.company.com:100/jde/owhtml/

TEST

https://jdeweb01dev.corporate.company.com:101/jde/owhtml/

There is only one IP configured for the above server FQDN but we will eventually give common name like JdeDev.company.com JdeTest.company.com or something.

We want to implement SSL cert for our Test/Dev environments, but how would we implement this on IIS or IBM Web SPhere, as well as on DNS level. Sine the only difference between the URLs is port numbers and both lead to different websites. I'm open for suggestions on how we can improve the design as well or how to make the current design work.

Another important thing to consider, the two websites will be accessed between two different Domain Forests which have transient Trust. This is a JDEdwards project.

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Please stop using different ports. IIS 8 and above allows you to use SNI, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability so multiple sites can share the same 443 port.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For questions that are not coding related, try asking on the relevant site from the list of [other StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology)

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure `HTTPS` binding in IIS site binding, just configure a certificate in IIS site binding module.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
Also, this could be accomplished by the `Netsh http` command.

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate

After you have set up the FQDN in DNS entries, you could specify the `Hostname` field in order to access the service with the server fully qualified domain name.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere supports multiple virtual hosts, each with its own alias(es), which can be a combination of DNS name and port. The built-in `default_host` will typically have an alias for the server/node name and the `*` wildcard for all ports. You then assign a specific virtual host to an application when you deploy it.